# How does the asp.net mvc framework deals with Null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some problem in understanding how does the asp.net mvc deal with Null values .
In the first scenario i have the following action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int labtestid, int visitid)
        {
try
            {
                var vlr = repository.GetVisitLabResult(labtestid,visitid);
                string desc = vlr.LabTest.Description; 
                repository.DeleteVisitLabResult(vlr);
                repository.Save();
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = labtestid, description =    desc }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Incase the repository method `var vlr = repository.GetVisitLabResult(labtestid,visitid);` does not return any result (`var vlr is null`) then the following exception will be raised on the `string desc = vlr.LabTest.Description`; **NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code**. So why did the framework raise an exception instead of just assigning a null value to the string desc !!!
BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the actual object itself is null. You have a null object and you're trying to access properties on it, hence the runtime will throw a `NullReferenceException`. You're best off checking if the object is null first before trying to access it's members :)